# Получить количество появлений объекта подряд, начиная с определённого дня

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Требуется посчитать количество появлений подряд по дням для каждой cell_name, начиная с текущей даты (От новой к старой). Пример DataFrame:

```
     cell_name    date_kpi
0    cell1  2019-04-17
1    cell2  2019-04-17
2    cell3  2019-04-17
3    cell4  2019-04-18
4    cell1  2019-04-18
5    cell1  2019-04-19
6    cell2  2019-04-19
```

Ожидаемый результат по данным из примера:

```
cell_name  qty
cell1      3
cell2      1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл ответ в англоязычном stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810868/pandas-count-consecutive-date-observations-within-groupby-object

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'cell_name': ['cell1','cell2','cell3','cell4','cell1','cell1','cell2'],
'date_kpi': ['17.04.2019','17.04.2019','17.04.2019','18.04.2019','18.04.2019','19.04.2019','19.04.2019']})
df.date_kpi = pd.to_datetime(df.date_kpi)
df = df.sort_values('date_kpi', ascending=0)

from_date = pd.to_datetime('19.04.2019')
g = df.groupby('cell_name')
df_new = df[(from_date - df['date_kpi']).dt.days == g.cumcount()].groupby('cell_name').size()
```

Результат:

```
cell_name
cell1    3
cell2    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то решение может быть таким:

```
df['date_kpi']= pd.to_datetime(df['date_kpi'])
df['diff'] = df.groupby('cell_name')['date_kpi'].diff().dt.days.fillna(1)
df = df.drop(df[df['diff'] != 1].index)
print(df.groupby(['cell_name'])['diff'].sum())
```

Результат:

```
cell_name
cell1    3.0
cell2    1.0
cell3    1.0
cell4    1.0
Name: diff, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Результат не соответствует ожидаемому. Смысл в том, что мы идём по датам от новой к старой. Смотрим 19 апреля - соты cell1: +1 день подряд, cell2 +1 день подряд. Дальше 18 апреля cell1 1+1=2 дня подряд. Cell 4 нам не интересна, т.к. её не было 19 апреля. Дальше 17 апреля cell1 2+1 = 3 дня подряд. Соты cell2 и cell3 нам не интересны, т.к. не шли предыдущие дни подряд. В итоге ответ как я привёл в примере.